# I converted a fragment to a dialog and now text colors have changed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-dialog

This is my first app. I had been setting a preference in an activity (with a fragment), but I want to move the fragment to a `DialogPreference`. It migrated okay, except my text colors have gone weird. See picture. The text should just be black, not white and gray. Any idea what I got wrong?

(Sorry, I know this is pretty sloppy code)

How it looks now:
[image]

My xml...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relLay_dialog_semester_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/select_semester_prompt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/select_semester_prompt" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayGradeSum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/select_semester_prompt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/semester_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:hint="@string/hint_editSemester" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/year_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/active_semesters_str"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linLayGradeSum"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linLayGradeSum"
        android:text="@string/active_semester_str"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/active_semesters_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/active_semesters_str"
        android:layout_below="@+id/active_semesters_str"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My extended DialogPreference class

```
public class SemesterDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {


SharedPreferences settings;
public static int YEAR_DEFAULT_VALUE = Activity_AddCourse.thisYear - Activity_AddCourse.baseYear;
public static int SEASON_DEFAULT_VALUE = Semester.getDefaultSemester().getSeasonInt();
public static int SEMESTER_DEFAULT_ID = 1;

String semester_id_key;

DBAdapter db;

// this is where I do everything view-related
@Override
public void onBindDialogView(View view){

        settings = getSharedPreferences();

        int curSemesterId = settings.getInt(semester_id_key, 1);

        db = new DBAdapter(this.getContext().getApplicationContext());
        db.open();
        Semester curSemester = db.getSemester(curSemesterId);
        db.close();

        ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = Activity_AddCourse.baseYear; i <= Activity_AddCourse.maxYear; i++)
        {
            years.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_year = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext().getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, years);

        Spinner spinYear = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.year_spinner);
        adapter_year.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinYear.setAdapter(adapter_year);
        spinYear.setSelection(curSemester.getYear() - Activity_AddCourse.baseYear);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.semester_spinner);
         ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_spinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getContext().getApplicationContext(),
         R.array.semester_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
         adapter_spinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         spinner.setAdapter(adapter_spinner);
         spinner.setSelection(Semester.seasonStringToInt(curSemester.getSeason()));


         db = new DBAdapter(this.getContext().getApplicationContext());
         db.open();
         Semester[] s = db.getAllSemesters();
         db.close();
         String activeSem;
         LinearLayout semesterList = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.active_semesters_list);
         if(s != null){ 
             for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
                 activeSem = s[i].getSemesterString();
                 TextView tv = (TextView) new TextView(this.getContext().getApplicationContext());
                 tv.setText(activeSem);
                 semesterList.addView(tv);
                 System.out.println(s[i].getSemesterString());
             }
        }


        super.onBindDialogView(view);
}


public SemesterDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.dialog_set_semester);

}

@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
    persistBoolean(positiveResult);
}
}
```

UPDATE:
The DialogPreference pops up from my settings activity, as shown below.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    }
}
```

Also, I was able to get the spinner text to black by making my own xml layouts for them, just as Huy Tran suggested. However, I had to make one for each the spinner_item and the spinner_dropdown_item. See below.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_year = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext().getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.my_spinner_item, years);
            Spinner spinYear = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.year_spinner);
            adapter_year.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Why did I have to do this? I don't know. Also, dropdown items are each now about 50% taller. I copied [exactly from source code](https://code.google.com/p/pdn-slatedroid/source/browse/trunk/eclair/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml?r=44) into my own xml and it still renders differently. Very weird.

Comment: can you post where you used this dialog. also are you using dark theme somewhere?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I have updated my question. I looked for usage of the dark theme, but couldn't find any references. *shrugs*

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout like below and use that layout in `setDropDownViewResource` instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`.

Create **my_spinner_dropdown_item.xml** in `res/layout`:

**EDITED:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    />
```

**my_spinner_item**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Try using margin to change the size of each item.

And then in your **SemesterDialogPreference**:

```
setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. However, I had to do this both for the `my_spinner_dropdown_item` resource and the `my_spinner_item` resource. Also, the vertical height of each dropdown item is now about 50% larger. I don't know why because my code is android's source code copy-pasted with only the textColor changed.